# Covenant between the pieces: dividing and keeping it whole

Tags: number, parashat-lech-lecha

In the covenant between the pieces (ברית בין הבתרים) all the animals had to be cut into two parts, but the two birds (dove תר and pigeon גוזל) are referred to as literally one bird (ואת הצפר לא בתר) that shall not be cut.

Rashi comments its about the nations and Israel (http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.15.10.2?lang=en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all).

But I wondered why all the ones had to be cut into two, but the 'two' seem to be kept whole (as one)?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47680/759

Answer (score 1):

In the future, the nations will be destroyed which is symbolized by the big animals being cut, while the Jews live eternally, which is symbolized by the birds staying whole. This is written in the second Rashi in Genesis 15:10.

> "but he did not divide the birds: Since the idol-worshipping nations are likened to bulls, rams, and goats, as it is said (Ps. 22:13): “Many bulls surrounded me, etc.,” and Scripture states (Dan. 8:20): “The ram that you saw, the one with horns, represents the kings of Media and Persia,” and Scripture states (ibid. verse 21): “And the he-goat is the king of Greece.” And the Israelites are likened to young doves, as it is said (Song of Songs 2:14): “My dove, in the clefts of the rock.” Therefore, he divided the animals, as an allusion that the nations will gradually perish. “But he did not divide the bird,” as an allusion that Israel will exist forever. [from Pirkei d’Rabbi Eliezer , ch. 28; Targum. Ps. 22: 13]"

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Perhaps you could cite a source to back up your claim, to help improve your answer? Hope to see you around.

Comment: Yes my source is the second Rashi in Genesis 15:10.

Comment: Would you mind editing that into your answer, and perhaps quoting or at least linking it?

Comment: I quoted it as I am unsure of how to link it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The splitting of the animals representing the umos ha'olam represents the splitting of the way gevurah and chesed are joined by the umos ha'olam to form society.

The implication of the joining of the tur (chesed, u'teruas melech bo) and gozal (din) is the way Hashem unites gevurah and chesed to create the society of the benei yisrael.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: This is really interesting because chesed and gevurah (ahava and yireh) are described by Chasidus as the two wings of a bird.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 animals that are cut represent the 3 patriarchs who are divided:

1. Abraham is divided from Lot.
2. Isaac is divided from Ishmael.
3. Jacob is divided from Esau.

Jacob's wives give birth to Judah and Joseph. The Torah unites them and also separates them. The two birds represent wholeness and the heavenly realm. Judah inherits Hebron that Abraham paid for, while Joseph inherits Shechem that Jacob paid for. These are the only two pieces of Canaan's land that were paid for by the patriarchs - hence why Judah and Joseph are entitled to them.

Judah and Joseph are the two uncut birds.

The concept of "Egypt" divided Abraham. After Lot experienced Egypt's land, this causes him to leave Abraham and look for eastern land that is like Egypt. Look at Genesis 13:10.

In the next chapter (Genesis 16) after the covenant of cut pieces (Genesis 15), Abraham has relations with Hagar, an Egyptian slave. Almost like Abraham is believing in the reality of Egypt and slavery in order to be fruitful. The covenant of cut pieces refers to Ishmael and the division between siblings of the patriarchs.

The covenant of cut pieces (Genesis 15) is about Ishmael (Genesis 16), just as much as the covenant of circumcision (Genesis 17) is about Isaac (Genesis 18). The covenant between the pieces refers to division, and the covenant of circumcision refers to closer examination.

There's emphasis on the number "four" with this covenant. There's two rows of four. 3 halves of the animals on each side, plus the whole bird on each side. Genesis 15:13, Genesis 15:16, and Exodus 20:5 all mention "four". Abraham through Joseph is four generations, hence it refers to the covenant of cut pieces.

I think Abraham is actually asking "when" he shall possess the land in Genesis 15:8. And God responds with the symbolism of the covenant. Genesis 15:18 God says to Abraham, "To your offspring, I assign this land."